# in-place shuffle torch.Tensor in the order of a numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I want to change the order of elements of a `torch.Tensor` from default to a `numpy.ndarray`. In other words, I want to shuffle it so that the order of its elements be specified with a numpy array; the important thing about this problem is that I don't want any third object to be created (because of memory limits)
Is there something like below code in python 2.7?

```
torch_tensor.shuffle(order)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Edit:*** This should be an in-place version:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

t = torch.rand(10)
print('Original Tensor:', t)

order = np.array(range(10))
np.random.shuffle(order)
print('Order:', order)

# in-place changing of values
t[np.array(range(10))] = t[order]
print('New Tensor:', t)
```

Output:

```
Original Tensor: tensor([ 0.3380,  0.3450,  0.2253,  0.0279,  0.3945,  0.6055,  0.1489,
         0.7676,  0.4213,  0.2683])
Order: [7 1 3 6 2 9 0 5 4 8]
New Tensor: tensor([ 0.7676,  0.3450,  0.0279,  0.1489,  0.2253,  0.2683,  0.3380,
         0.6055,  0.3945,  0.4213])
```

I hope this is roughly what you were looking for!

Comment: @MarziehHeidari No, it wasn't in-place (sorry if I didn't point it out clearly enough) - but I got an idea right now, this version is definitely in-place, even though I would prefer out-of-place as PyTorch can be problematic with in-place operations. However, the above edited version is definitely in-place.

Comment: @MarziehHeidari I cannot say something about your memory. Only that this code above is swapping the values to the given order using a numpy array within an in-place operation - because this is what you actually asked for - more I cannot do :)

Comment: Although this definitely an in-place operation, I cannot exactly say how the assignment is carried out on a hardware level and how much extra memory is taken for this operation (actually I wouldn't be sure that `torch_tensor.shuffle(order)` meets your requirement to absolutely not occupy extra memory). Generally the official website discourages in-place operations, PyTorch is mainly designed to be used with out-of-place operations. Considering this is there is probably no better alternative for doing such an operation in-place.

Comment: @MarziehHeidari Thinking about it: Doing such an operation completely without occupying extra memory would be extremely inefficient because you are reading and writing from/to the same place and you have to make sure to don't produce any conflicts. And such inefficient methods do not really represent the spirit of an GPU accelerated framework. Especially for PyTorch which is designed mainly for out-of-place operations.

Comment: So in-place operation was not the solution to my problem in first place. Maybe I should consider loading data in batches so that I do not run out of space. I'm new in deep learning. Sorry for taking your time and thank you for your detailed answers.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree - trying to reduce memory pressure at other places is probably much more fertile! Adjusting batch size is always an good and easy way to start. *(Btw. I would be glad if you would vote on the answer and if you think it answers your question as posted, accept it to value the time spend on it, thanks! :)*